# While statement infinite looping

Tags: php, while-loop

I can't for the life of me figure out why this function is in an infinite loop. It's probably something simple I'm just not seeing. It is given the year, then it prints out every month from 7/[start-year] until this month.

```
function showmonths($year) {

    $start = strtotime($year.'-07-01');
    $end = strtotime("now");

while($end >= $start) {
   $months[] = strtotime("-1 month", $end);
   $end = strtotime("-1 month", $end);
}
return $months; 
}
```

Comment: the function looks weird but it is at least non an endless loop

Comment: This function does not loop infinitely for me and works normally. The problem must be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Hint: you can use `$months[]=$end=strtotime("-1 month",$end);` instead `$months[] = strtotime("-1 month", $end);
 $end = strtotime("-1 month", $end);`

Comment: Can you show us how are you using this function, please?